# Recursive Tree Algorithm to sum total cost of a project

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Does any one have an idea to solve this problem, but only using a generic Tree?

I need to sum all the nodes, but respecting the edge values.

If the edge between two nodes > 1 thans the cost of the subtree most be multiplicated for the whole subtree.

The solution must be using a tree algorithm

Thanks

http://oi39.tinypic.com/24buik7.jpg

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: In the picture that you posted is a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) which is not a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an object `Node`, containing it's own `cost` and a set of outgoing `edges`, each having a weight, you could do the following. (**Note** I assume you have a DAG, as mentioned by pkacprzak, since the picture you posted does not show a tree)

```
class Edge
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public Node Start { get; set; }
    public Node End { get set; }
}

class Node
{
    private int cost;
    private IEnumerable<Edge> edges;

    // ...

    public int Cost()
    {
        int totalCost = cost;

        foreach (var edge in edges)
        {
            totalCost += edge.Weight * edge.End.Cost();
        }

        return totalCost;
    }
}
```

You should call `Cost` on the source of your DAG (that is, the node without incoming edges). If you have multiple sources, it is up to you what you want to achieve.